# Jquery data attributes as selectors

Tags: jquery

I have input with either some given or empty "data-file":

```
<input type="text" value="path/to/file.gif" name="some_file" data-fileid=".selector" data-file="/path/to/file.gif">
```

The cancel:

```
<button class="cancel" type="button" accesskey="c">Cancel</button>
```

I am manipulating the textfield to insert images which is fine, but when it comes to manipulating via data attributes, the button do not work:

```
        var inputBg = $('fieldset:visible input[name*="file"]');

        var dataOld = inputBg.data('file');
        var dataSel = inputBg.data('fileid');

        $('.cancel').click(function() {
          $(inputBg).val(dataOld); // revert to old stored value if any
          $(dataSel).css('background', 'none'); // remove background from .selector
        });
```

I am using a jquery.ui.tabs, thats why I have: "fieldset:visible".
But the cancel button do not work. Any idea whats missing? 
Thanks

UPDATE:
Problem identified, I have to do binding to ui.tabs, but still looking for suggestions on other route, because my binding is not bullet-proof. I have to do duplication :(
I also have to change relative path to absolute path on "data-file".

Comment: have you tried to debug your code using firebug in order to check that your handler is called (breakpoint) and then check the values of inputBG, dataOld and dataSel?

Comment: I think your selector is the problem here. I would use a class on it or id attribute if you prefer that...

Comment: @mathroc: yes. But I suspect the problem is more on jquery.ui.tabs context.

Comment: console.log(inputBg); //do this after defining it, let's see whether you have an input at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to do the buttons inside and outside ui.tabs. Regarding duplication I can create another function that serves for any call.

I will change this as an answer if any better reply. Thanks to all